# Commandbutton flushing view state prior to performing action

Tags: apex, visualforce

this one is a confidence killer... I must be doing something fundamentally wrong!

I have a list var in controller that I render to a pageblocktable.
When I click 'update' custom button to save changes - my list var has been flushed back to null, and I get a 'null object' runtime error.

Any suggestions? Has me stumped.

VF:

```
<apex:pageblockbuttons> 
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveChanges}" immediate="false" rerender="msgs"/>
        </apex:pageblockbuttons>
            <apex:outputPanel id="theTable">
                <apex:pageblocktable value="{!templateList}" var="t">
                    <apex:column headervalue="Template Name" value="{!t.name}"/>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Template Description" value="{!t.description}"/>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Template Contents" ><apex:outputText value="{!t.htmlvalue}" escape="false"/></apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Available to Use" value="{!t.available}"/>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Dimension 1" ><apex:inputField value="{!t.et.pw_d1__c}"/></apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Dimension 2" ><apex:inputField value="{!t.et.pw_d2__c}"/></apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Dimension 3" ><apex:inputField value="{!t.et.pw_d3__c}"/></apex:column>
                </apex:pageblocktable>
            </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageblock>
```

And the controller:

```
public with sharing class YourController {

    public static list<template> templateList {get; set;}

    public pageReference saveChanges(){
        // grab the records and upsert
        system.debug('templateList=>'+templateList); // this is proving templateList is null on arrival!
        List<pw_email_metadata__c> updList = new List<pw_email_metadata__c>();
        for(template t : templateList){
            updList.add(t.et);
        }
        if(!updList.isEmpty()) {
            try{
                upsert updList pw_templateId__c;
                ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Saved');
                ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            } catch (exception e){
                ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error on save:'+e);
                ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class template {
        public pw_email_metadata__c et { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of your page and controller?  One thing I wonder, is how you have your templateList defined and exposed to the VF page?  Also, you are rendering a msgs element, where is it on your page?

Comment: Whoops - the templatelist is declared as a public static ie. public static list<template> templateList {get; set;}  template is a custom wrapper class.

Comment: msgs is a <apex:pageMessages /> element - I tried to keep the bits that do work out of the question to try to limit noise.

Comment: How is `templateList` initialised and assigned values?

Comment: SaveChanges called from your Save button is trying to save a controller-instance (i.e. non-static) templateList. Basically, I'm not sure you can update a static templateList with your Save button, templateList should be non-static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `templateList` is declared as `static`, `static` variables are not included within the view state. This is covered in the documentation [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_static.htm).

> Static methods, variables, or initialization code are associated with a class, and are only allowed in outer classes. When you declare a method or variable as static, it's initialized only once when a class is loaded. **Static variables aren't transmitted as part of the view state for a Visualforce page.**

Comment: Lol you stare at things long enough you don't see the obvious: thanks to all for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

As @altius_rup mentioned in the comments, this should work fine if you remove the `static` keyword from the `templateList` member.

```
public list<template> templateList { get; set; }
```